# Anchor not working with javascript

Tags: javascript

Ancor not working with javascript.

When I load my page with URL#anchor the anchor works.
When I set it by javascript as example. The page is loading but the anchor does not work.
(by the way: for my purpose its nessesary the reload takes place).

Here my script (comments what i tried to).. and actualy i tried much more...

```
function hash_test() {  
    href = window.location.href;
     alert(href);    
     if (href.lastIndexOf('#') > 0){  //remove hash if present
     href = href.substring(0,href.lastIndexOf('#'));    
     }
     alert(href);
/*   window.location.href = href;
     window.location.hash = '#beitrag9';*/    // does not work to
     window.location.href = href +'#beitrag9';
     window.location.reload(true); 
}
```

Comment: What is this anchor supposed to be accomplishing?

Comment: Did you call the `hash_test()` function from your code ?

Comment: Why does the page need to be reloaded? Without that information, this sounds like an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You mean that the page reloads but content does not scroll to the position of the anchor `beitrag9` ?

Comment: Yes Paolo - thats the thing!

Comment: Hello Adam - as you see i have coded an attempt so no XY..
The page has to be reloaded because there are some DB-Changes made to display by reload. and they shoul be visible

Comment: Hy Marox - sure did i call this function (and many timers :-)
as I told the page does reload...

Comment: @ratmalwer you've posted a question about the code for your proposed solution, not a question about the actual problem of needing to get new database values.  So yes... XY problem.  If you need to get database changes, why not use an Ajax call and load the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working for me: just tried right now with this web page

```
function hash_test() {  
    href = window.location.href;
     alert(href);    
     if (href.lastIndexOf('#') > 0){  //remove hash if present
     href = href.substring(0,href.lastIndexOf('#'));    
     }
     window.location.href = href +'#35711597';
     window.location.reload(true); 
}
```

Pasting the function in the console and calling `hash_test()` reopen this page and brings me here, on this answer.

Maybe in some circumstances (page reload does not occurr upon direct user interaction) or on some browsers it doesn't work.

You may try then to force the page to always scroll programmatically to the anchor upon onload with this at the bottom of the header.

```
<script>
    window.onload=function()
    {
        var href,
            hash;

        href = window.location.href;
        if( href.lastIndexOf( '#' ) != -1 )
        {
            hash = href.substring( href.indexOf( '#' ) );
            if( hash.lastIndexOf( '?' ) != -1 )
            {
                // cut away query string as well (if present)
                hash = hash.substring( 0, hash.indexOf( '?' ) );
            }
            window.location.hash = hash;
        }
    };
</script>
```

---

**Bottom line:**

Anchors are a well known and supported feature of HTML (even StackOverflow relies on them to produce links to specific answers).

However the use you're making of them is quite "edge": the code snippet I proposed is a hack rather than a canonical solution and you may expect inconsistent behaviour across browsers.

Let me now try to give some more context to your original question:

It seem the reason you **need** to reload the page is to send some data to the server and (eventually) show some changes on the page's content.

If you have to do that, since a decade or so, there is **ajax**.

You send data to the server, wait (asyncronously) other output data back from the server and then programmatically apply changes to the page.

This gives the user a better interface experience and the final result is consistent.

Now you have a "decent" solution. I suggest you to consider **ajax** (eventually with the aid of the jQuery library) for future improvements of the site you're working on or for future projects.

Comment: Thanks Paolo... that works on my testscript .. now i try it in my page

Comment: Hi Paolo - short response: It works in FF and Crome but in IE11 a bit shity but I will live with it...

Comment: @ratmalwer - I edited the answer - see my bottom line.

Comment: Hi Paolo - you are right. - As I manipulate the item by Ajax, I consider your suggestion ...
Thanks you are a nice guy!